# How many threads per GAE instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

Does anyone know how many threads does GAE instance (**Java**, not python) create and under what conditions? The conditions of new instance creation are well described, but there doesn't seem to be any information about how many requests can one multithreaded Java instance serve.

Answer (score 0):

An instance only processes one thread at a time. The first request in the queue is assigned to a free instance as soon as it is created. Once it completes that request, it is free again and another request is assigned to it. One request at a time, per instance.

Comment: That is true for GAE Python. GAE Java already supports concurrent requests. (also Python2.7 runtime which is in testing)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that multiple requests are handled concurrently, possibly even on different servers, but within one instance there is only a single thread.